# Evaluate:$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x \sin x \cos x}{(a^2 \cos^2 x+b^2 \sin^2 x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the integral of

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin x\cos x}{(a^2 \cos^2 x+b^2 \sin^2 x)^2}dx$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200858/integral-of-int-fracx-sinx-cosxa2-sin2-x-b2-cos2-x2-dx

Comment: You were the one who asked the duplicate question.. Did you forget you had asked the same question..?

Comment: yupp...i forgot...thanks